# ORA-00933 while using Oracle PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, pivot

I am facing oracle error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" while using below SQL onto Oracle Database 10.2.0.1; Where as same sql working fine onto Oracle Database 11.1.0.7
Kindly, look into and suggest where is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
    SELECT concept,
            rdcno,
            rdc_mart,
            subcat,
            mart,
            artname,
            SUM (m1) m1,
            SUM (m2) m2,
            SUM (m3) m3,
            SUM (m4) m4,
            SUM (m5) m5,
            SUM (m6) m6,
            SUM (m7) m7,
            SUM (m8) m8,
            SUM (m9) m9,
            SUM (m10) m10,
            SUM (m11) m11,
            SUM (m12) m12,
            SUM (m13) m13,
            SUM (m14) m14,
            SUM (m15) m15,
            SUM (m16) m16,
            SUM (m17) m17,
            SUM (m18) m18,
            SUM (m19) m19,
            SUM (m20) m20,
            SUM (m21) m21,
            SUM (m22) m22,
            SUM (m23) m23,
            SUM (m24) m24
       FROM (  SELECT concept,
                      rdcno,
                      rdc_mart,
                      subcat,
                      mart,
                      artname,
                      month_index12,
                      index_picked,
                      SUM (deseasonalized_value) deseasonalized_value
                 FROM (SELECT concept,
                              rdcno,
                              rdcno || '-' || MART rdc_mart,
                              subcat,
                              MART,
                              ARTNAME,
                              s_ind month_index12,
                              index_picked,
                              NVL (deseasonalized_value, 0) deseasonalized_value
                         FROM (SELECT s.concept,
                                      s.rdcno,
                                      s.subcat "SUBCAT",
                                      s.mart "MART",
                                      s."ARTNAME",
                                      s."YEAR",
                                      s."BMONTH",
                                      s."PAIRS",
                                      s."VALUE",
                                      i."MONTH_INDEX",
                                      s.month_index s_ind,
                                      i.seasonal_index,
                                      i.index_picked,
                                      CASE
                                         WHEN i.seasonal_index IS NULL
                                              OR i.seasonal_index = 0
                                         THEN
                                            0
                                         ELSE
                                            ROUND (
                                               (CASE
                                                   WHEN s.pairs < 0 THEN 0
                                                   ELSE s.pairs
                                                END)
                                               / i.seasonal_index,
                                               5)
                                      END
                                         deseasonalized_value
                                 FROM ps_sales_data s, ps_seasonal_index i
                                WHERE     i.concept(+) = s.concept
                                      AND i.rdcno(+) = s.rdcno
                                      AND i.subcat(+) = s.subcat
                                      AND (i.month_index = s.month_index
                                           OR i.month_index + 12 = s.month_index)))
             GROUP BY concept,
                      rdcno,
                      rdc_mart,
                      subcat,
                      mart,
                      artname,
                      month_index12,
                      index_picked) PIVOT (MAX (deseasonalized_value)
                                    FOR month_index12
                                    IN  (1 AS M1,
                                        2 AS M2,
                                        3 AS M3,
                                        4 AS M4,
                                        5 AS M5,
                                        6 AS M6,
                                        7 AS M7,
                                        8 AS M8,
                                        9 AS M9,
                                        10 AS M10,
                                        11 AS M11,
                                        12 AS M12,
                                        13 AS M13,
                                        14 AS M14,
                                        15 AS M15,
                                        16 AS M16,
                                        17 AS M17,
                                        18 AS M18,
                                        19 AS M19,
                                        20 AS M20,
                                        21 AS M21,
                                        22 AS M22,
                                        23 AS M23,
                                        24 AS M24))
   GROUP BY concept,
            rdcno,
            rdc_mart,
            subcat,
            mart,
            artname;
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know pivot is a new feature in 11g:

http://psoug.org/reference/ora_operators.html#oppv

But there is a long topic about how to do the same before 11g:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:766825833740